# Emojis make display: block divs taller

Tags: html, css

When using emojis inside `display: block` `div` elements, they get slightly taller. This only seems to happen with `block` elements; `inline` ones have the same height with and without emojis. Is there any way to keep them the same height?
I've already tried setting `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`, neither of which had any effect. Increasing `padding` made everything taller, but didn't even them out.

https://jsfiddle.net/719kbg8u/2/

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">Baguette  (block)</div>
<div class="outer">No baguette (block)</div>
<br><br>
<div class="outer inline">Baguette  (inline)</div>
<br>
<div class="outer inline">No baguette (inline)</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some emoji occupy a greater **line-height**.
Being strict about the line height might help:

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  line-height: 1em; /* since of emoji */
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">Baguette  (block)</div>
<div class="outer">No baguette (block)</div>
<br><br>
<div class="outer inline">Baguette  (inline)</div>
<br>
<div class="outer inline">No baguette (inline)</div>
```